# not able to query using email id in mysql tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am using the following table structure

```
Create table SP_Rest_User
(
Client_Id varchar(50) references SP_Rest_API_Key(Client_ID) , 
User_Id varchar(255) primary key , 
password_hash varchar(255), 
is_user_active TINYINT(1),
Role varchar(50),
contact_id varchar(50) references sp_rest_contact(contact_id),Entity_Id varchar(50),
last_login_date_time datetime,
emailid varchar(100) collate armscii8_general_ci
);
```

i have added the following records

```
insert into SP_Rest_User values('C00001','VINOTH','06a085d63dae33a9',1,0,'1234','1111',now(),'vinoth.m@gmail.com');
insert into SP_Rest_User values('C00002','SENTHIL','06a085d63dae33a9',1,0,'1234','1111',now(),'senthil.c@yahoo.com');
insert into SP_Rest_User values('C00002','VENKAT','06a085d63dae33a9',1,0,'1234','1111',now(),'venkat.y@gmail.com');
```

not to query the records using the email id column. getting error as record not found.

```
SELECT * FROM sp_rest_user where emailid like 'venkat.y@gmail.com';
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM sp_rest_user where emailid = 'venkat.y@gmail.com'; is also not working in mysql db.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
SELECT * FROM SP_Rest_User where emailid like 'venkat.y@gmail.com';
```

With `SP_Rest_User`.

> In MySQL, databases correspond to directories within the data
>   directory. Each table within a database corresponds to at least one
>   file within the database directory (and possibly more, depending on
>   the storage engine). Triggers also correspond to files. Consequently,
>   the case sensitivity of the underlying operating system plays a part
>   in the case sensitivity of database, table, and trigger names. This
>   means such names are not case sensitive in Windows, but are case
>   sensitive in most varieties of Unix. One notable exception is OS X,
>   which is Unix-based but uses a default file system type (HFS+) that is
>   not case sensitive. However, OS X also supports UFS volumes, which are
>   case sensitive just as on any Unix.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html